# Python Unicode behaviour

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a word `êtes` in two files and I tried converting it into different formats.

1) I opened the file with `codecs.open('test1.txt',encoding='ISO-8859-2')` and then did `word.encode('utf-8')`. The word read as `\xc4\x99tes`

2) I opened another file with the same word, but with `codecs.open('test2.txt',encoding='utf-8')`. This time the word read as `\xeates`

Shouldn't both be giving the same output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they should not give the same output. The first will be a byte string, and the second will be a Unicode string.

It appears your first file is encoded with [`ISO-8859-1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso-8859-1), not [`ISO-8859-2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso-8859-2). The `ê` (`\xea`) is being translated into `ę` (`\u0119`) instead, and its UTF-8 representation is the two bytes `\xc4\x99`.

The second file appears to be properly encoded in UTF-8. If you want to see the actual character rather than its hex representation you need to `print` it.